# Haskell lambda function - parse error on input ‘)’

Tags: haskell

I have the following code in Haskell and I want to change the line

```
toNanoStmt (VarDeclStmt _ array)= SeqList (toNanoStmt (map (\(VarDecl _ (Id a x) (Just exp))) array ))
```

Basically I want to use VarDeclStmt by creating a sequence of assign statements. A SeqList takes a list of statements. I have the list of VarDecls! And I have again use a map to convert the varDeclArr to a list of assignments. But am getting this error:

parse error on input ‘)’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda-expression has no body.

After parameters, there has to come a right arrow `->` followed by the body, for example:

```
addTwo = (\x -> x + 2)
```

So in your case you need to do something like this:

```
toNanoStmt (VarDeclStmt _ array)= SeqList (toNanoStmt (map (\(VarDecl _ (Id a x) (Just exp)) -> <body goes here>) array ))
```

Comment: And the lambda probably should handle `Nothing` as well as `Just exp`.